# Configurar hierarquia de "Activity" no "AndroidManifest"

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity

Estou a tentar entender como posso configurar uma `Activity` para retornar para a `Activity` anterior no `AndroidManifest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hierarquia das `Activity` é configurada no `manifest`, onde podemos definir qual a navegação esperada entre as mesmas:

**Exemplo:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ResultActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

No exemplo em cima, a `MainActivity` está definida como antecessor da `ResultActivity`.

Este assunto é abordado em algum detalhe nos exemplos de treino em:

[Preservar Navegação ao iniciar uma Atividade](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Comment: Tentei fazer isso e meu aplicativo deu crash.

Comment: Achei esse negócio de configurar hierarquia das atividades meio prolixa, ela é realmente necessária? Pelo que entendi a documentação cita duas possíveis situações quando uma notificação é clicada, abrir a atividade no topo do backstack atual ou abrir em um novo backstack que só contém a atividade. Em nenhum dos casos vejo necessidade de especificar a hierarquia, eu simplesmente clico na notificação e a atividade é aberta no topo do backstack ou em um novo backstack dependendo das Intent flags que foram usadas. `taskAffinity` e `excludeFromRecents` servem para quê, _edge cases_ da navegação?

Answer (score 0):

Nao entendi sua pergunta direito mas todas as `Activity`'s vao sair da `Activity MAIN`, quando vc chama o metodo [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> ela vai fechar a atual e retornar para qual foi chamada.

**Exemplo:**

```
MAIN --> Activity1 --> Activity2 \/

MAIN <-- Activity1 <-- Activity2
```

Avançar: [`new Intent();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Retornar: [`onBackPressed();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Lembrando que isso ja é feito automatico nao é preciso implentar o `onBackPressed()` a nao ser que queria mais alguma função.